# Error. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, object

Everything was working fine before. The only thing I did was added an Edit Button, then this error occurred. Even though I undo the Edit Button, the error still persist. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with line 26?

```
SqlCommand cmdDoctorInfo = new SqlCommand("SELECT d.* FROM Doctorinfo p, Department d WHERE d.DepartmentID = p.DepartmentID AND p.userId = @UserID", conDoctorInfo);
Line 26:   cmdDoctorInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["UserId"].ToString()); 
SqlDataReader dtrPatient = cmdDoctorInfo.ExecuteReader();
```

Edit:
For some unknown reason, it suddenly works fine after I closed and opened the app over and over again.
Now when I add back the Edit Button, the error comes back. Here is the Edit Button code (2nd line)

```
<td align="center">
                    <asp:Button ID="editButton" runat="server" OnClick="editButton_Click" Text="Edit" />
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="picFileUpload" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="uploadButton" runat="server" OnClick="uploadButton_Click" Text="Upload"/>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="messageLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                </td>
```

I don't understand how does adding an Edit button cause the error. Please enlighten me.

Comment: I think your `Session["UserId"]` is `null`. Debug your program and see.

Answer (score 6):

May be your Session["UserId"] is null. try this:

```
cmdDoctorInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID",Convert.ToString(Session["UserId"]));
```

Convert.ToString will not break your code even Session["UserId"] is null. Because Convert.ToString() handles null, while ToString() doesn't.

Comment: If it solved your issue please mark my answer as up.:)

Comment: `Convert.ToString` can break your code even more since it could silently swallow an exceptional `UserID` (`null`). I guess that he gets a database error now. But even if not it's better to handle the case that it's `null` more explicitly.

Comment: Yeah logically Convert.ToString affect your system if it will not break your code but is another approach to handle exception for String.

Comment: @MuhammadOmair: exceptions are a good thing if they prevent you from incorrect data in your database. So not the exception is the bug which has to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The only object which can be `null` in the code you are showing is the `Session` object. You are using `ToString` which results in this error if it's null.

You could check that:

```
object userIdObj = Session["UserId"];
if(userIdObj != null)
{
    // use the correct type, i presume int
    int userID = int.Parse(userIdObj.ToString());
    cmdDoctorInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userID);
}
```